# Using Symfony2 with Salesforce PHP toolkit

Tags: symfony, salesforce

I want to use the Salesforce php toolkit(https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP) within Symfony2.
Has anyone had experience doing this?

What is the best route to take?
A bundle, entity or service?

If I just namespace my initial Salesforce.php, which will provide the connection to Salesforce and leave the toolkits require_once files for its other classes.
Then, I guess, any bundles I write can use this namesspace and directly use this connection throughout my app?

Sorry this is a bit vague, any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested but you can take a look at https://github.com/phpforce/salesforce-bundle

Comment: It seems this one is more entire https://github.com/ddeboer/DdeboerSalesforceClientBundle

Comment: Thanks, looks useful. Having trouble configuring it...will press on.

Comment: @Duncan, Did you successfully configured DdeboerSalesforceMapperBundle and DdeboerSalesforceClientBundle ?

Is it mandatory to use both of them or just the client bundle will do ?